# Multiple patch installation issue

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have created a Basic MSI installer and its version is v2.5.0.  Using the .ism file that was used to create v2.5.0 installer I created a patch v2.5.1.0 under patch design.  Now again using the same .ism file I created another patch v2.5.7.0.  When I created patch versions for v2.5.1.xx (eg. 2.5.1.1, 2.5.1.2...etc) and installed one over the another i.e. first install v.2.5.0 then install patch 2.5.1.1 and then 2.5.1.2, it works fine.  Similarly I created patch versions for v2.5.7.xx (eg. 2.5.7.1, 2.5.7.2...etc) and installed one over the another, it works fine.  But if I install say 2.5.1.1 and then install patch 2.5.7.1 then during 2.5.7.1 installation it gives this error.

****The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch.****

In the .ism that creates 2.5.7.xx patch installer, I set the property 'Minor Update to Target RTM Version' to 'Yes'.  This allowed me to install 2.5.7.xx over 2.5.1.xx, say 2.5.1.1 to 2.5.7.1 works fine, but then if I install 2.5.7.2 over 2.5.7.1 then it fails and asks for original source i.e. v2.5.7.0.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> > if I install 2.5.7.2 over 2.5.7.1 then it fails and asks for original source i.e. v2.5.7.0

[It looks like the second patch is created over the base package, it need to be created on top of the first patch.   2.5.7.2 need to be created on top of 2.5.7.1, then it can apply on top of 2.5.7.1 ]